# Use hashMap from another class

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to implement a simple login form in my application. I have created a class `client.java` in which I instantiated a hashMap:

```
package com.xbank.event;
import com.xbank.service.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public  class Client {
    
    public static Map<String, Client> clientMap;
    public String name;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public Double balance;
    public String address;
    public String phone;
    
    // Default Constructor
    public Client() {
        name = "";
        address = "";
        phone = "";
        username = "";
        password = "";
        balance = 0.0;
        clientMap = new HashMap<String, Client>();
    }

    // Parameterized Constructor
    public Client(String name, String username,String password, String phone, String address, Date date) {
        
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    
    public void verify_login(String username, String password)
    {
        
        Client client = new Client();
        
        client = new Client(username, password, name, address, phone, new Date());
        clientMap.put(username, client);
        
        if (clientMap.containsKey(username)) {
            System.out.println(username);
            client = client.clientMap.get(username);
            if(client.password.equals(password)) {
                System.out.println(password);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Wrong password");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong username");
        }
        
    }
    
    
    public static  Map<String, Client> getLoginInfo() {
        return clientMap;
    }
    
    
    void showClientInfo() {
        System.out.println("Name: "+name);
        System.out.println("Phone Name: "+phone);
        System.out.println("Address Name: "+address);
    }
    
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    
    
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    
    
    // end of class
}
```

I want to access the hashMap from a GUI class that I have created, and set the conditions to login, but I can't find a way to do this

GUI class:

```
public class GUI {
    
    // remake the screen
    public void remakeScreen(JFrame frame, JPanel f) {
        f.setLayout(null); 
        frame.setContentPane(f);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }   
    
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    //               Login Related Screen Functions               |
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    // sign in form which is displayed at the start of program
    public void openSignInForm(JFrame frame, Client client) {
        JPanel f = new JPanel();        
        f.setBackground(Color.black);
        
        // main screen picture
        JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java/com/xbank/icon/image-1.png"));
        imgLabel.setBounds(300,50,450, 400 );
        f.add(imgLabel);
        
        //---------------------------------Creating Labels------------------------------------------        
        JLabel l_hSignIn = new JLabel("Sign In");
        l_hSignIn.setFont( l_hSignIn.getFont().deriveFont(30f) );
        l_hSignIn.setBounds(120,24,100, 40);
        l_hSignIn.setForeground(Color.white);
        f.add(l_hSignIn);
        
        JLabel l_UserName = new JLabel("User Name");
        l_UserName.setBounds(140,120,100, 40);
        l_UserName.setForeground(Color.white);
        f.add(l_UserName);
        
        JLabel l_Password = new JLabel("Password");
        l_Password.setBounds(140,200,100, 40);
        l_Password.setForeground(Color.white);
        f.add(l_Password);
        
        JLabel l_Signup = new JLabel("Dont have an account?");
        l_Signup.setBounds(20,380,150, 40);
        l_Signup.setForeground(Color.white);
        f.add(l_Signup);
    
        //-----------------------------------Creating TextFields--------------------------------------------------      
        JTextField tf_UserName = new JTextField();
        tf_UserName.setBounds(80,170,180, 25);
        f.add(tf_UserName);
        
        JPasswordField tf_Password = new JPasswordField();
        tf_Password.setBounds(80,250,180, 25);
        f.add(tf_Password);
            
        //-------------------------------------Creating Buttons--------------------------------------------------
        JButton btn_SignIn = new JButton("Sign In");
        btn_SignIn.setFont( btn_SignIn.getFont().deriveFont(18f) );
        btn_SignIn.setBackground( new Color(0, 204, 153) );
        btn_SignIn.setForeground(Color.black);
        btn_SignIn.setBounds(120,300,110, 40);
        f.add(btn_SignIn);
        
        JButton btn_SignUp = new JButton("Sign Up");
        btn_SignUp.setFont( btn_SignUp.getFont().deriveFont(18f) );
        btn_SignUp.setBackground( new Color(0, 204, 153) );
        btn_SignUp.setForeground(Color.black);
        btn_SignUp.setBounds(180,380,110, 40);
        f.add(btn_SignUp);
        
        //---------------------------------------SignUp functionality----------------------------------------------
        
                btn_SignUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                        
                    open_Signup_form_1(frame, client);                      
                    }
                });
        
        //----------------------------------Sign in Functionality-----------------------------------------------        
        btn_SignIn.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
                Map<String, Client> user = (Map<String, Client>) new Client();
//              HashMap<String, Client> logininfo = new HashMap<String, Client>();              
                user = user
                
                if(e.getSource() == btn_SignIn) {
                    String userId = tf_UserName.getText();
                    String password = String.valueOf(tf_Password.getPassword());
                    
                    if(client.containsKey(userId)) {
                         if (client.get(userId).equals(password)) {                             
                                        Client Client = new Client( client.getName(), null, null, null, null, null );
                                        frame.remove(f);
                                        frame.repaint();
                                        frame.validate();
                                        openClientMenu(frame,client);                           
                         }else {
                             System.out.println("Wrong username or password.");
                         }                      
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Wrong username or password.");
                    }
                }
                }       
        });
        remakeScreen(frame, f);
    }
```

Comment: can you be more specific about what your question is?

Comment: also, check your code -> user = user this renders it uncompilable

Comment: my question is how do I access to the username and password values stored in the hashMap from my GUI class

Comment: Besides that your GUI-class is missing `()`, wouldn't passing the Client-Object to the constructor be your answer? Or vice-versa

Comment: by working with an instance of the Client class. It might be better if you stopped with UI coding for now, and started learning the basics first.

Comment: Your HashMap is **public** and **static**, just access it directly using the class name followed by the variable name: `if (Client.clientMap.containsKey(userId)) { ... }`

Comment: Quick 7m video - does a great job at explaining constructor keywords https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgBk8HC7jbU&ab_channel=CodingwithJohn